# How to properly set a bool property in an obj-c repo from a Swift project?

Tags: objective-c, swift, m13pdfkit

Odd question and odd situation. I am using a repo from GitHub (M13PDFKit) in my swift project. It presents more cleanly that the others i have peeked at. Trouble is, the bool settings that i manage in Swift prior to my present() seem to have absolutely no effect. No errors but the (internally-set) defaults of YES are not being overridden by my swift-project setting of = false.

I am currently at a loss for how to proceed to correct this.

I have not explored the bridging scenario as the repo is functioning properly (with the exception of these settings of course).

I have tried a few variants, wondering if i can fool the compiler, which might somehow not be making the obj-c bool false from the swift false. I have tried a few variants, both of which don't seem to work. The code in the repo is hit, just no values other than the defaults set therein are seen:

```
pdfKBasicPDFViewerFullSCreen.setValue(false, forKey: "_enableBookmarks")
pdfKBasicPDFViewerFullSCreen.enableOpening = false
```

Likely a simple issue, i am just not seeing it. Thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly "bridging", like `NSNumber(bool: false)` ?

Comment: I'm feeling kinda stupid here. I tried the thought danh, which required this format: = NSNumber(value: false) as! Bool  ... but no change, buuuuut, then i tried actually tapping the icon, and it faded quickly away to nothing, never to reappear. So i flipped back to the regular  = false, and see the same behaviour. Never ever experienced that before. So.. it would appear that the toolbar is not refreshing its view after property changes! Now i must dig deeper as i cannot leave this repo in place like this.